# Restructure a csv file into a txt file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file with multiple rows with this structure

```
name lastname group password
john smith    sales abc1
liza jones    hr    abc2
```

The list is around 500 rows long, and I would like to create a txt file with this structure

```
  - name: j.smith 
    password: abc1 
    groups: admins
```

I want to reproduce spacing, so before the "-" character you will see there are 2 spaces, and five spaces before password as this is needed in the final txt file.

Comment: CSV stands for "comma-separated values" but those values are not comma-separated. The delimiter here is just whitespace. This question also does not show an honest attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: I showed the csv the way it shows if opened in Excel for readibility purposes. I've been able to read the csv with pandas but not been able restructure as expected. In terms of attempts I have tried stuff like "txt =  txt + '\n\n* [{}] {}\n{}'.format(root, text, field)" yet did not included as it might confuse more than help

Comment: Not sure why you are using pandas when you could use readline, split the line at commas, and format the list with f'name:{line[0]}\npassword:......etc.

Comment: @JimRobinson I agree that pandas doesn't make much sense here, but readline? You should almost certainly just use the `csv` module here.

Comment: "I showed the csv the way it shows if opened in Excel for readibility purposes" **don't do that**. Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in general you should not use pandas `iterrows`, because it is very slow, I am going to use it in my answer in part because you do not need to use pandas at all: you just want to iterate over the rows in your CSV:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'name': {0: 'john', 1: 'liza'}, 'lastname': {0: 'smith', 1: 'jones'}, 'group': {0: 'sales', 1: 'hr'}, 'password': {0: 'abc1', 1: 'abc2'}})

template = """- name: {fname[0]}. {lname}
  password: {pword}
  groups: {groups}
"""

with open('output.txt', 'w') as fp:
    # iterrows returns the index, which we ignore with _
    for _, (name, lastname, group, password) in df.iterrows():
        fp.write(template.format(fname = name, lname = lastname, pword = password, groups = group))
```

Here we use a template string that we will substitute the values into using keyword arguments in the string `format` method. This will write the output to `output.txt`. Notice the keywords correspond directly to the keywords used in the template. The resulting text file appears as:

```
- name: j. smith
  password: abc1
  groups: sales
- name: l. jones
  password: abc2
  groups: hr
```